# Mongo pipeline aggregation for specific values in the same field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data is of the form:

```
defect                  week                        Cost  
aaaa                    1                       123123  
bbbb                    1                       2132131  
cccc                    1                       213213  
erea                    1                       123  
asdsad                  1                       12343  
dddd                    1                       123214  
sadsad                  1                       13123  
eeee                    1                       1313  
aaaa                    2                       141591.45  
bbbb                    2                       2451950.65  
cccc                    2                       245194.95  
erea                    2                       141.45  
asdsad                  2                       14194.45  
dddd                    2                       141696.1  
sadsad                  2                       15091.45  
eeee                    2                       1509.95  
aaaa                    3                       261944.1825  
bbbb                    3                       4536108.703  
cccc                    3                       453610.6575  
erea                    3                       261.6825  
asdsad                  3                       26259.7325  
dddd                    3                       262137.785  
sadsad                  3                       27919.1825  
eeee                    3                       2793.4075
```

I need to perform an aggregation on the defects but I dont need the aggregated cost for all the defects(Just a few).I have got the list of defects
that I need to perform aggregation on.
Eg: The list of defects will be stored in a variable as shown below:

```
var specificdefects = [ aaaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd, eeee ]
```

My ultimate aim is to get the aggregated cost for the specific defects in each week(similar to below).

```
defect  1           2           3   
aaaa    213213      123213      21313  
bbbb    234534.3    135534.3    23444.3  
cccc    257987.73   149087.73   25788.73  
dddd    283786.503  163996.503  28367.603  
eeee    312165.1533 180396.1533 31204.3633
```

I know that I can pass each defect to the `$match` clause and then perform the aggregation.But then each defect would require a seperate query(which is not desired).
Can we do this using a single query? If so, how?

Comment: You can use aggregation. Use $match with $in list of defects to filter the matching documents followed by $group on defect and week with $sum accumulator to sum  the costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongo aggregation just like below:

```
db.someCollection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                defect: {
                    $in: ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd', 'eeee'] // Match given defects
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    defect: '$defect', // Group on defect
                    week: '$week'  // Also, group on week
                },
                sumOfCost: {
                    $sum: '$cost' // Sum the cost for this unique group of defect and week
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Which should show result like below:

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "defect": "aaaa",
            "week: 1
        },
        "sumOfCost": 213213
    }
    {
        "_id": {
            "defect": 'aaaa',
            "week": 2
        },
        "sumOfCost: 123213
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.Thanks